# Getting a high amount of unreachable hosts and Network errors in local Network

Tags: docker, zabbix

I have a medium sized Zabbix Setup. I have one Central Zabbix Server and Multiple Zabbix Proxies, one at each Site I'm monitoring. All of those are setup with the Official Docker Containers, the main Server:

- postgres:11-alpine
- zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql:alpine-4.0-latest
- zabbix/zabbix-snmptraps:alpine-4.0-latest
- zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql:alpine-4.0-latest

The Proxies are all just a single Docker image:

- zabbix/zabbix-proxy-sqlite3:ubuntu-4.0-latest

The Proxies mostly monitor other VMs on in the same VMWare vCenter.

The Problem that arises is that on the Proxies in the Logs I see a very high amount of network errors that all look somewhat like this:

`Zabbix agent item "some.item" on host "SOME HOST" failed: first network error, wait for 15 seconds`

From that it arises, that there is a High Amount of False Positive Problems in Zabbix. Mostly `Zabbix agent on SOME HOST is unreachable for 5 minutes`, but sometimes also other Problems that are triggered by `.nodata()`.

There is also a high amount of missing item Data, since the hosts with network errors are considered "offline" for a bit and no items from them are checked.

I've also tried to investigate it a bit and found the source code that produces this error: https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix/blob/135111a0fd1f16f203226f8632881ac0a8bf541a/src/zabbix_server/poller/poller.c#L302

Unfortunatly the same message seems to be triggerd in 3 different failure cases: https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix/blob/135111a0fd1f16f203226f8632881ac0a8bf541a/src/zabbix_server/poller/poller.c#L749

Therefore I couldn't really find out anything that way. I also of cause looked at cpu, ram, disk and network usage on the proxies and couldn't find anything that looked out of the norm for me.

How should I proceed to find out the cause of these errors? Has anyone else had this happen to them?

Comment: How your poller performance graph looks like? Are they 100%busy?

Comment: No, the poller performance is always around 55% +-10%. Same for all other process types, I've tweaked the config so that the deault zabbix proxy monitoring template dosen't throw any warnings.

Comment: What seems to happen, is that *some* item failes, due to whatever reason idk. That triggers the host to become unavailable (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/items/unreachability#unavailable_host) disabeling all checks on the host for a bit. Then it comes back online and some other item fails. The big Problems seems to be that I have some hosts with so many items that whatever the reason for failure (checking the same item with zabbix_get works right away) it happens often enough to cause problems.

Comment: i have the same issue here, lots of false positives

Answer (score 0):

Check the network stats for errors in the RX-ERR and TX-ERR columns on some of your hosts and proxy servers:

`$ ifconfig -s
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
docker0   1500   953410      0      0 0       1691396      0      0      0 BMRU
enp0s31f  1500 300757888      4      0 0      192733308      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536 23324198      0      0 0      23324198      0      0      0 LRU
tap0      1500  1317609      0      0 0       4530946      0      9      0 BMPU
tun0      1500        0      0      0 0           589      0      0      0 MOPRU
vboxnet0  1500        0      0      0 0          2324      0      0      0 BMU
veth20f8  1500    11690      0      0 0        538547      0      0      0 BMRU
veth2238  1500        0      0      0 0            76      0      0      0 BMRU
virbr0    1500  1317609      0      0 0       4519309      0      0      0 BMU
wlp2s0    1500  5584389      0      0 0       4387278      0      0      0 BMU`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunatly I don't have any Transmit or Receive errors. So it seems the problem is somwhere else. (I checked both in the container and on the host itself)

Comment: Another basic test is a continues ping to see if there is any packet loss

Comment: Done that, didn't reveal anything. What I've now figured out is that a more specific error from zabbix is `Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[1.1.1.1]:10050]: [4] Interrupted system call` I got that by increasing the DebugLevel for a bit.

Comment: 1.1.1.1 doesn't look like a valid IP for your Zabbix agent, is that the real IP listed in the error log? Use nmap or telnet to verify the servers can access the agents.
You can also use tcping from:
https://github.com/AyoobAli/TCPing

Comment: no, that is not the real IP, that's just an easy IP to replace the real one with.

Comment: Also to clarify, the requests on the hosts work most of the time. A single item sometimes (but not always) fails, that causes checks to be disabled for 15 seconds.

Comment: Then Tshark is your tool to debug the flow that fails

Comment: I feel like you might be right. But for today that goes over my head, I've already reduced the problems a bit with just some tweaking in zabbix elswhere, it does however not solve the problem, just makes it workable for a bit longer until I find the time to analize this further.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot more digging. I also posted this question, along with my discoveries on the Zabbix forum: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-troubleshooting-and-problems/393381-getting-a-high-amount-of-unreachable-hosts-and-network-errors-in-local-network

I solved the problem for myself, but one error just vanished after I didn't thouch the system for two weeks, not sure what exactly happend.

The other Problem I encounterd, was because I am kinda new to Linux in some ways and didn't quite grasp how systemd works.

Systemd looks for a pid file, in the case of zabbix it looks for it in `/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid`, I did not tell Zabbix where to write that file to. In the end the fix was in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf` to insert `PidFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf`.

Before that Zabbix Agent started and was happy. But it didn't tell systemd about it, so after a timeout where systemd let's deamons startup it just restarted zabbix agent. If the Proxy tried to connect to the agent while it was not running... it produced network errors.